# AFNetworking build error: "Declaration of anonymous class must be a definition"

Tags: afnetworking

I am starting up with AFNetworking to replace the sadly-defunct ASIHTTPRequest. People seem to love this new "AFNetworking" but it doesn't build in my project and I can't figure out why. I'm getting build errors starting on `Class class = NSClassFromString(className);` in `HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest:success:failure` in the file `AFHTTPClient.m`.

The error is "Declaration of anonymous class must be a definition" and I have asked teh google but not gotten anything. Help?

Context:

```
- (AFHTTPRequestOperation *)HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)urlRequest 
                                                    success:(void (^)(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject))success
                                                    failure:(void (^)(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error))failure
{
    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = nil;
    NSString *className = nil;
    NSEnumerator *enumerator = [self.registeredHTTPOperationClassNames reverseObjectEnumerator];
    while (!operation && (className = [enumerator nextObject])) {
        Class class = NSClassFromString(className);
        if (class && [class canProcessRequest:urlRequest]) {
            operation = [[(AFHTTPRequestOperation *)[class alloc] initWithRequest:urlRequest] autorelease];
        }
    }
```

**EDIT: Solved per answer below. Patch file [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/124984/patch.diff).**

**EDIT 2:** These changes have been pulled into the newest AFNetworking, so anyone finding this in the future: **Just download a fresh version and you're all set.** Also, how's the future? Hello future.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to get around the compiler error by renaming the variable "class" to something else. Unfortunately, I was not able to figure out why I was getting the problem. Here's a clue: it happened to me when I added AFNetworking to a big existing project with unknown compiler flags. When I added AFNetworking to a fresh new project, I didn't hit the problem at all.

Comment: I changed the "class" to "classVC", resolved my problem, thanks